# Поменять сортировку записей в RSS-ленте wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rss

По умолчанию в главном feed (site.com/feed/) выводятся только последние опубликованные новые записи. Хочу поменять сортировку записей в rss, чтобы выводились последние измененные записи. Попробовал такой код добавить в functions.php, но в главном feed по-прежнему выводятся только новые записи.

```
/* Модификация RSS */
function add_new_post_types_to_feed( $query ) {
  // Выходим если это запрос не фидов
  if( ! $query->is_feed || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'add_new_post_types_to_feed');
/* Модификация RSS */
```